# Binding background of datatemplate in contentcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind the background color of a `TextBox` and use a converter. However, I can't figure out the correct binding due to the `TextBox` being in a `DataTemplate` and in a `ContentControl`.

The `DebuggingConverter` doesn't fire unless I set the binding path from `Path=StateColor` to `Path=.`

Here is the xaml :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="{Binding SelectedDeviceCol2, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Mode=TwoWay}" >
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource readOnlyToEnabledConverter}}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:VMDeviceCommand}">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Height="24" IsEnabled="True" Click="Button_Click_GetObjectProperty"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:DateTime}">
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=.}"
                            SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                            FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"  
                            IsTodayHighlighted="True" >
                    </DatePicker>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged">
                        <TextBox.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=StateColor, Converter={StaticResource DebuggingConverter}}"/>
                        </TextBox.Background>
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>                 
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:UInt16}">
                    <xctk:IntegerUpDown  Text="{Binding Path=.}" ValueChanged="UpDownBase_OnValueChanged" >
                    </xctk:IntegerUpDown>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentControl doesn't have a `StateColor` property, so the Binding never gets its value and never has anything to pass to a converter.

If the ContentControl's DataContext has a `StateColor` property, that's easy:

```
<SolidColorBrush 
    Color="{Binding DataContext.StateColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Converter={StaticResource DebuggingConverter}}"
    />
```